# VSIS failed to install extension

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install some extensions on VS by VSIS.
when finished downloading,the VSIS started to install,it reported need to close the VS.
showing the window like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plVbs.jpg)
the devenv.exe is the VS itself.I pressed the buttom,waited for a long time but it failed to end the task.If I choose to cancel，it will exit,but still leaving a process;After trying 3 times,it left 3 processes on my computer ,and I can't kill them by taskmanager.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmShG.jpg)

to solve the problem.to install some extensions.to kill the exsit processes devenv.exe.